# How to reduce MSE and improve R2 in Linear Regression model

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, linear-regression

I try to perform an example of linear regression model in python.
The aim is find a linear relationship among two features in my dataset, this features are 'Year' and 'Obesity (%)'. I want train my model to predict the future trend of obesity in the world.
The problem is that my MSE is too high and R2 too low. How can improve my model?

This is the [link](https://www.kaggle.com/amanarora/obesity-among-adults-by-country-19752016/data?select=obesity-cleaned.csv) where I found the data set; Obesity-cleaned.csv

CODE

```py
#Analysis of obesity by country

import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sb
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import sklearn
from sklearn import metrics
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn import preprocessing

address = 'C:/Users/Andre/Desktop/Python/firstMN/obesity-cleaned.csv'
dt = pd.read_csv(address)

#eliminate superfluos data
dt.drop(dt['Obesity (%)'][dt['Obesity (%)'].values == 'No data'].index, inplace=True)  

for i in range(len(dt)):
   dt['Obesity (%)'].values[i] = float(dt['Obesity (%)'].values[i].split()[0])  

obMean = dt['Obesity (%)'].mean() 
print('%0.3f' %obMean, '\n') 

dt['Obesity (%)'] = dt['Obesity (%)'].astype(float)  #converto il tipo in float 

group = dt.groupby('Country')


print(group[['Year', 'Obesity (%)']].mean(), '\n') 

dt1 = dt[dt['Sex'] == 'Both sexes']   

print(dt1[dt1['Obesity (%)'] == dt1['Obesity (%)'].max()], '\n')   

sb.lmplot('Year', 'Obesity (%)', dt1)
plt.show()

#linear regression predictions

group1 = dt1.groupby('Year')

x = np.array(np.linspace(1975, 2016, 2016-1975+1)).tolist() 
y = np.array([group1['Obesity (%)'].mean()]).tolist()[0]

x1 = np.array([1975, 1976, 1977, 1978, 1979, 1980, 1981, 1982, 1983, 1984, 1985, 1986, 1987, 1988, 1989, 1990, 1991, 1992, 1993, 1994, 1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002 , 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016 ]).reshape((-1, 1))  
y1 = np.array([group1['Obesity (%)'].mean()]).reshape(-1, 1)     

lr = LinearRegression(fit_intercept=False)
lr.fit(x1, y1) 

plt.plot(x, y) 
plt.show() 

print('Coefficients: ', lr.coef_)  
print("Intercept: ", lr.intercept_ )

y_hat = lr.predict(x1)
print('MSE: ', sklearn.metrics.mean_squared_error(y_hat, y1)) 
print('R^2: ', lr.score(x1, y1) ) 
print('var: ', y1.var())
```

OUTPUT

```
Coefficients:  [[0.00626604]]
Intercept:  0.0
MSE:  15.09451970012738
R^2:  0.03779706109503678
var:  15.687459567838905 

Correlation among years and obesity (%) is:  (0.9960492544111168, 1.0885274634054143e-43)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `fit_intercept=False` in your code. If the true model intercept is truly zero, the intercept term will be approximately zero making it unnecessary to set `fit_intercept` to `False`. You're essentially constraining the model without, to my knowledge, any reason to do so (correct me if I'm wrong).

From the [scikit-learn documentation on the linear regression](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html):

> Whether to calculate the intercept for this model. If set to False, no intercept will be used in calculations (i.e. **data is expected to be centered**).

I didn't see anywhere where you centered the data. Thus, your results are flawed. To remedy the situation, simply remove `fit_intercept=False` since it is `True` by default.

Answer (score 4):

Forcing `fit_intercept=False` is a **huge** constraint for the model, and you should be sure that you know exactly what you are doing before deciding to do so.

Fitting without an intercept in simple linear regression practically means that, when our single feature X is 0, the response Y should be also 0; here, it means that in the "year 0" (whatever that may mean), the Obesity should also be 0. Given that, the poor results reported are hardly a surprise (ML is not magic, and it is certainly implied that we do include realistic assumptions in our models).

It's not clear here why you have decided to do so, but I highly doubt it is what you intended to do. You should remove this unnecessary constraint from your model.

Comment: Yes, by just removing `fit_intercept=False` and using the same code provided in the question, I was able to reduce the MSE value to `0.124`